# Bond interest reported on Box 3 of a 1099-MISC

Tags: united-states, income-tax, bonds

A friend of mine has a significant amount of variable interest bonds. In certain cases, I believe the issuer could have paid the bond off with stock. His broker reported the interest on these bonds on Box 3 of a 1099-MISC. Any idea why?

I am thinking that the 1099 might be wrong but a corrected 1099 would not affect the amount of tax he has to pay.

Comment: "Could have" -- Do you mean you think they did, or that you think they should, or that you think they might? ... If it wouldn't affect the tax, I honestly wouldn't worry about it right now; if the IRS has a problem with it, I believe you can assert that you answered in good faith and tell them to take it up with the broker.

Comment: @keshlam I believe the debtor had the option of paying off the bond with stock. As it turns out it was cheaper for them to pay it off with cash. Therefore they paid it off with cash.

Comment: I'd be rather surprised if so, since the value of stock is, by definition, variable so it isn't clear what would constitute complete payoff. And not everyone wants stock, and I don't think the bond's issuer can unilaterally make that decision, though I suppose they might offer it as an alternative. 
I am going to assume this is a misunderstanding unless someone can point to specific text saying otherwise.

Comment: The bond defines what counts as a complete payoff. I have considered buying such a bond but I decided not to.